# Importing class into angular 4 component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have something like this in a separate file

```
export namespace Test{
    export class TestClass{
        Default: {Read: ['blah']}
    }
}
```

I am able to include it in angular 4 component by import, but when it comes to instantiate, it fails to resolve. Please see below:

```
import { Test } from 'SomeFile';
const derp: Test.TestClass = new Test.TestClass(); <--- This works
let t = derp.Default.Read; <--- Fails
```

Comment: can you give more info about the error please

Comment: Try setting a debugger before the `let t` line and inspect `derp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you have defined `derp` not `depr`

second, if you want to have a default value for the property `Default` you should define it like:

```
Default: any = {Read: ['blah']}
```

Now for all instance of the class you could have `Default.Read` which is `'blah'`

so final class:

```
export namespace Test{
    export class TestClass{
        Default: any = {Read: ['blah']}
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Test } from 'SomeFile';
const derp: Test.TestClass = new Test.TestClass(); 
let t = derp.Default.Read;
```